# Best way to render React Components inside HTML templates?

Tags: html, django, reactjs, webpack, server-side-rendering

I would like to to use React with Django non Single Page App way - Django will take care of routing, and rendering HTML templates and serving data.

React should be used just on some specific components inside HTML page for eg. (dropdowns, autocomplete, modals), ideally being able to just drop for eg. div element with a class inside HTML and pass props for React component.

What’s the best - maintainable, scalable solution to go about this ?

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't what you want to do, given that React has a pretty robust ecosystem around it for building performant single page applications (SPA's). You should be able to decouple your React site from your Django app. Then you'd be able to throw up your React app on a performant CDN, rather than having your Django server hosting every visitor.

But if you insist, the most straightforward way to proceed would probably be to create an `index.js` & `index.html` at each Django route. In other words, make a separate "React app" at each route, which Django will serve as users go to each endpoint. I've seen this done before. It's laggy and inefficient (relative to an SPA), but can be done.

If you really intend to go so far as to write raw HTML/CSS/JS and just use React for bits and pieces in between, you'll probably be looking to invoke [`ReactDOM.render`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html) using a variety of second arguments (called `container`) rather than the standard React-y way of doing a single `ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));` for the whole app to inject into a barebones HTML template.

I notice you tagged your question with server side rendering. If that is a hard requirement for you for some reason, I'd look into using [next.js](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/), a Node framework optimized for exactly that.

Comment: But what if I don’t need spa?

Answer (score 0):

See [django-jsx](https://github.com/caktus/django-jsx) package and also [server side rendering](https://medium.com/meural-product-development/setting-up-server-side-rendering-with-react-redux-and-django-4d6f4d2fd705) paper. I'm not a frontend specialist but when I've faced such problem, my friends offered me to google `isomorphic app with django and react`.

Answer (score 0):

I found this [add React to an HTML page in one minute](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#quickly-try-jsx) page/example to be absolutely painless in rendering a React component inside of a Django template!